# Keycloak 8: User with username 'admin' already added

Tags: docker, jboss, docker-compose, keycloak

I cannot start Keycloak container using Ansible and Docker Compose. I'am getting error:

> User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'

I have 3 Ansible jobs:

Create network:

```
- name: Create a internal network
  docker_network:
    name: internal
```

Setup Postgres:

```
- name: "Install Postgres"
  docker_compose:
    project_name: posgressdb
    restarted: true
    pull: yes
    definition:
      version: '2'
      services:
        postgres:
          image: postgres:12.1
          container_name: postgres
          restart: always
          env_file:
            - /etc/app/db.env
          networks:
            - internal
          volumes:
            - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - /etc/app/createdb.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-app-db.sh
          ports:
            - "5432:5432"
      volumes:
        postgres-data:
      networks:
        internal:
          external:
            name: internal
```

Create Keycloak container:

```
- name: Install keycloak
  docker_compose:
    project_name: appauth
    restarted: true
    pull: yes
    definition:
      version: '2'
      services:
        keycloak:
          image: jboss/keycloak:8.0.1
          container_name: keycloak
          restart: always
          environment:
            - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
            - DB_ADDR=postgres
            - DB_PORT=5432
            - DB_SCHEMA=public
            - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
            - DB_USER=keycloak
            - DB_PASSWORD=keycloak
            - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
            - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
          networks:
            - internal
      networks:
        internal:
          external:
            name: internal
```

Does anyone have any idea why I get this error?

**EDIT**

If I downgrade Keycloak to version 7 it starts normally!

Comment: That user is probably there from the previous run. Clean postgres-data volume = start db from the scratch.

Comment: @JanGaraj no it is not. I run ansible playbook on clean environment and still get the same error.

Comment: I had the same issue. Deleting all docker containers and images and redownloading them somehow resolved it.

Comment: @cib It appears it crashes if container is stopped then started again. Created an issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-12896

Answer (score 96):

Just to clarify the other answers. I had the same issue. What helped for me was:

1. stop all containers
2. comment out the two relevant lines

   ```yaml
   version: "3"

   services:
     keycloak:
       image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
       environment:
         # KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
         # KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: pass
         ...
   ```
3. start all containers;
4. wait until keycloak container has successfully started
5. stop all containers, again
6. comment back in the two lines from above

   ```yaml
   version: "3"

   services:
     keycloak:
       image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
       environment:
         KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
         KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: pass
         ...
   ```
7. start all containers

This time (and subsequent times) it worked. Keycloak was running and the admin user was registered and working as expected.

Comment: This worked and its hard to believe. Perhaps from not shutting down the container correctly.

Comment: @Madeo That sounds like you may have accidentally commented out all variables? Instead of just the two...?

Comment: Too strange fix but it works !

Comment: thanks this worked for me! just found out I needed to also comment the environment line, otherwise I was having an error

Comment: doesnt work for me

Answer (score 14):

This happens when Keycloak is interrupted during boot. After this, command which attempts to add admin user starts to fail. In Keycloak 7 this wasn't fatal, but in 8.0.1 this line was added to `/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh` which aborts the entire startup script:

```
set -eou pipefail
```

Related issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-12896

Comment: You can repair the failing container by first copying this file from the container to your local machine "docker cp keycloak:/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh  ." Comment out the line "set -eou pipefail", copy it back into the container using "docker cp docker-entrypoint.sh keycloak:/opt/jboss/tools/" and restart the container.
After a clean startup/shutdown, you could restore (uncomment) this line again.

Answer (score 10):

The reason commenting out the `KEYCLOAK_USER` works is it forces a recreation of the container. The same can be accomplished with:

```
docker rm -f keycloak
docker compose up keycloak
```

Comment: It is good to notice that this will remove all configurations done from the admin panel

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. After commenting out the KEYCLOAK_USER env variables in docker-compose and updating the stack, the container started again.

```
docker_compose:
project_name: appauth
restarted: true
pull: yes
definition:
  version: '2'
  services:
    keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak:8.0.1
      container_name: keycloak
      restart: always
      environment:
        - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
        - DB_ADDR=postgres
        - DB_PORT=5432
        - DB_SCHEMA=public
        - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
        - DB_USER=keycloak
        - DB_PASSWORD=keycloak
        #- KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
        #- KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      networks:
        - internal
  networks:
    internal:
      external:
        name: internal
```

Comment: doesnt work. same problem persists for me. User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'

Answer (score 7):

According to my findings, the best way to set this default user is **NOT** by adding it via environment variables, but via the following command:

```
docker exec <CONTAINER> /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD>
```

As per [the official documentation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/README.md#creating-admin-account).

Comment: This was a nice piece of info. Every keycloak-related questions seem oriented to docker-compose only. Worked just fine

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer for simple docker instance

Answer (score 4):

I use Keycloak 12 where I still see this problem when the startup is interrupted. I could see that removing the file "keycloak-add-user.json" and restarting the container works.

Idea is to integrate this logic into container startup. I developed a simple custom-entrypoint script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "executing the custom entry point script"

FILE=/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "keycloak-add-user.json exist, hence deleting it"
    rm $FILE
fi
echo "executing the entry point script from original image"
source  "/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

And I ensured to rebuild the keycloak image with appropriate adaptations to Entrypoint
in Dockerfile during the initial deployment.

```
ARG DEFAULT_IMAGE_BASEURL_APPS

FROM "${DEFAULT_IMAGE_BASEURL_APPS}/jboss/keycloak:12.0.1"

COPY custom-entrypoint.sh /opt/jboss/tools/custom-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/tools/custom-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

As our deployment is on-premise, the access to the development team is not that easy. All that our first line support could do is try giving a restart of the server where we deployed. Hence the idea of this workaround.

Comment: Thanks, My current installation hasn't a database (is a keycloak standalone image). To restore, I
1. create a new image by `docker commit my-keycloak-container` and `docker tag <sha> keycloak-temp`;
2. create a temporary container from the new image: `docker run -it --entrypoint=sh keycloak-temp`;
3. rename the file `keycloak-add-user.json` to `keycloak-add-user.json.old`;
4. create a new image
5. run a new container with `--entrypoint=/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh`

Comment: You need to add permissions to the shell script on host: `chmod +x custom-entrypoint.sh`.

Comment: where do you put this file and when to execute it?

Answer (score 1):

The way I got past this was to replace `set -eou pipefail` with `# set -eou pipefail` within the container file systems.

Logged in as root on my docker host and then edited each of the files returned by this search:

```
find /var/lib/docker/overlay2 | grep /opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Solutions is good but restarting all containers and start again is worthless because my docker-compose file has 7 services.

I resolved the issue in two steps.

1. first I commend these two lines of code like other fellows did

> ```
>  #- KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
>  #- KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
> ```

2. Then new terminal I run this command and it works.

> docker-compose up keycloak

keycloak is a ServiceName

Comment: doesnt work. same problem persists for me. User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'

Answer (score 1):

For other users with this problem and none of the previous answers have helped, check your connection to the database, this error usually appears if keycloak cannot connect to the database.

Test in Keycloak 8 with Docker.

Comment: any version with keycloak doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the solution by 
[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413297/thomas) as but it sometimes works sometimes does not.

The issue is that Keycloak on boot does not find the db required, so it gets interrupted as [Zmey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151614/zmey) mentions.  Have you tried in the second ansible job to add `depends_on: - postgres` ?

Having the same issue but with docker-compose, i first started with the postgres container in order to create the necessary dbs (manual step) `docker-compose up postgres` and the i booted the entire setup `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me when I used to shut down the Keycloak containers in Portainer and tried to get them up and running again.

I can prevent the error by also 'removing' the container after I've shut it down (both in Portainer) and then running `docker-compose up`. Make sure not to remove any volumes attached to your containers else you may lose data.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add user before server start or want it look like a classic migration, build custom image with admin parameters passed

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest

ARG ADMIN_USERNAME
ARG ADMIN_PASSWORD

RUN /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -u $ADMIN_USERNAME -p $ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

docker-compose:

```yaml
  auth_service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ADMIN_USERNAME: ${KEYCLOAK_USERNAME}
        ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
```

(do not add KEYCLOAK_USERNAME/KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD to the environment section)

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, solved it by changing two lines in my `docker-compose`

`From this:`

```
KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
```

`To this:`

```
KEYCLOAK_USER: newadmin
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: newadmin
```

and `restart` containers

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this issue with Keycloak "jboss/keycloak:11.0.3" running in Docker, error:

> `User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json`'

Adicional info, was running with **PostgreSQL v13.2** also in Docker. I create some schemas for other resources but I wasn't creating the schema for the Keycloak, so the solution was for my case, run in postgres the **create schema command**:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS keycloak AUTHORIZATION postgres;
```

NOTE: Hope this helps, none of other solutions shared in this post solved my issue.

Answer (score -6):

You can also stop the containers and simply remove associated volumes.

If you don't know wiwh volume is associated to your keycloak container, run:

```sh
docker-compose down
for vol in $(docker volume ls --format {{.Name}}); do
    docker volume rm $vol
done
```

Comment: This script will remove all of your docker volumes, not only the one for keycloak container.