# Why does I see the following error when I am try to create docker container of Keycloak instalation by using SQL external database?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to install the Keycloak with SQL databse server by using docker-compose file. IT run but keycloak stop with following error.

```
    "ssl-context" => "applicationSSC",


    "proxy-address-forwarding" => expression "${env.PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING:false}",


    "enable-http2" => true


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("server" => "default-server"),


        ("host" => "default-host")


    ],


    "alias" => ["localhost"]


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("server" => "default-server"),


        ("host" => "default-host"),


        ("location" => "/")


    ],


    "handler" => "welcome-content"


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("server" => "default-server"),


        ("host" => "default-host"),


        ("setting" => "http-invoker")


    ],


    "http-authentication-factory" => "application-http-authentication"


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("servlet-container" => "default")


    ]


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("servlet-container" => "default"),


        ("setting" => "jsp")


    ]


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("servlet-container" => "default"),


        ("setting" => "websockets")


    ]


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("configuration" => "handler"),


        ("file" => "welcome-content")


    ],


    "path" => expression "${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("application-security-domain" => "other")


    ],


    "security-domain" => "ApplicationDomain"


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [("subsystem" => "weld")]


}, {


    "operation" => "boottime-controller-initializer-step",


    "address" => []


}, {


    "operation" => "add-deployer-chains",


    "address" => []


}]: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException


    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.RejectingExecutor.execute(RejectingExecutor.java:37)

    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.rejectShutdown(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2029)   

    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.execute(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:757)   

    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.notification.NotificationSupports$NonBlockingNotificationSupport.emit(NotificationSupports.java:95)   

    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.notifyModificationsComplete(OperationContextImpl.java:517)
   
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.releaseStepLocks(OperationContextImpl.java:1245) 

    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1534)
  
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1492)

    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1356)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:910)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:790)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:466)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1427)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:559)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:572)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:534)


    at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:470)


    at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:414)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:473)


    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


    Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Executor is being shut down


        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.rejectShutdown(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2031)


        ... 18 more


rUser with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'
```

I have search other tickets but no able to fix this issue. Username is not an issue I have delete all and try again, not able to run.

My Docker compose file is following

```
version: "3.2"

services:
    mssql:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        environment:
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - SA_PASSWORD=Password!23
            - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    mssqlscripts:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools
        depends_on:
            - mssql
        command: /bin/bash -c 'until /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S mssql -U sa -P "Password!23" -Q "create database Keycloak"; do sleep 5; done'
    keycloak:
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
        depends_on:
            - mssql
            - mssqlscripts
        ports:
            - "8443:8080"
        environment:
            - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
            - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
            - DB_VENDOR=mssql
            - DB_USER=sa
            - DB_PASSWORD=Password!23
            - DB_ADDR=mssql
            - DB_DATABASE=Keycloak
```

When I try to comment the user name and Pass

```
    "socket-binding" => "https",


    "ssl-context" => "applicationSSC",


    "proxy-address-forwarding" => expression "${env.PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING:false}",


    "enable-http2" => true


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("server" => "default-server"),


        ("host" => "default-host")


    ],


    "alias" => ["localhost"]


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("server" => "default-server"),


        ("host" => "default-host"),


        ("location" => "/")


    ],


    "handler" => "welcome-content"


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("server" => "default-server"),


        ("host" => "default-host"),


        ("setting" => "http-invoker")


    ],


    "http-authentication-factory" => "application-http-authentication"


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("servlet-container" => "default")


    ]


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("servlet-container" => "default"),


        ("setting" => "jsp")


    ]


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("servlet-container" => "default"),


        ("setting" => "websockets")


    ]


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("configuration" => "handler"),


        ("file" => "welcome-content")


    ],


    "path" => expression "${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [


        ("subsystem" => "undertow"),


        ("application-security-domain" => "other")


    ],


    "security-domain" => "ApplicationDomain"


}, {


    "operation" => "add",


    "address" => [("subsystem" => "weld")]


}, {


    "operation" => "boottime-controller-initializer-step",


    "address" => []


}, {


    "operation" => "add-deployer-chains",


    "address" => []


}]: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException


    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.RejectingExecutor.execute(RejectingExecutor.java:37)


    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.rejectShutdown(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2029)


    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.execute(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:757)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.notification.NotificationSupports$NonBlockingNotificationSupport.emit(NotificationSupports.java:95)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.notifyModificationsComplete(OperationContextImpl.java:517)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.releaseStepLocks(OperationContextImpl.java:1245)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1534)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1492)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1356)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:910)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:790)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:466)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1427)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:559)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:572)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:534)


    at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:470)


    at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:414)


    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:473)


    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


    Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Executor is being shut down


        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.rejectShutdown(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2031)


        ... 18 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak 8: User with username 'admin' already added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599620/keycloak-8-user-with-username-admin-already-added)

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply and I already did this, and see the same error just not the last line. I also edit the question with new error.

Comment: I am not able to exec because the docker contaner is not running.

Comment: Are there any other exceptions or errors in the log prior to this one? This looks like a subsequent error.

Comment: No only this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Docker, keyclick works differently than k8s. Docker composes files run step by step if you run the file and it is filed it populates the database with a username and password. Now there are two options one is to try adding a different username and password after each failed try. Another option is clean up the database before trying after every failed run to avoid the error user already has been added. I hope this helps.